# Use Generator Inlet as Outlet

Tags: electrical

Note: this is the *opposite* of backfeeding, for which there are many questions and answers. Have not seen anything on the internet about this scenario.

Say you had a 240V generator inlet with a 50A breaker professionally installed, and you needed to run a 240V appliance close to where that inlet is, but where there is no 240V outlet available. The hypothetical appliance is three-wire; the outlet is 4-wire/4-prong. Aside from the interlock/lockout kit on the breaker panel, is there anything dangerous or wrong with wiring the appliance with the matching generator plug and powering the appliance through the inlet?

Comment: Not possible. It is interlocked so it can't receive power from the grid. Do you wish to permanently abandon the generator capability?

Comment: Can't plug a plug into a plug. Powering an inlet is hazardous and illegal (exposed energized prongs.) The interlock you obviously plan to defeat. The problems here are myriad.

Comment: Totally agree with @Ecnerwal and harp .  This is a very very dangerous idea. If installed, it would require bypassing the generator interlock, which puts lineman at risk, not only that, you have open prongs powered up, if anybody touched them, big shock.  VERY VERY BAAAAAAAD IDEA ALL THE WAY AROUND. DON'T DO IT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A reverse suicide cord only works if *prongs are energized*

And that is just as bad as a suicide cord.

You are talking about putting 240V on the prongs of a generator inlet.  What happens when a child opens up the door and touches it?  Or what if your socket has a metal sleeve around it (as many do) and you put it in a little wonky and short prongs together with it?

Prongs should not be energized. End of discussion.

### You would need to remove the interlock in any case. So take one more step.

The interlock is there to assure the generator inlet cannot be energized at the same time as the utility service.  So you will need to remove the interlock to energize that inlet.

Since you are doing that much work, do *a little more* work and swap the inlet for a proper outlet.

"I want to switch it back and forth between generator inlet and EV outlet".

Fine, when you switch, change both the interlock and the inlet/outlet.

Comment: True, and I suppose this answers the implicit question I did not ask - is it just a matter of outlet / inlet direction rather than something I'm not thinking of? Swapping out the inlet itself makes sense here rather than having to run an additional circuit (given the also-unstated temporary nature of the hypothetical scenario :) )

Comment: Yeah, change the socket and remove the interlock and that should be it.  It's a permanent change, but it could be followed by another permanent change next week :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a huge safety issue as the inlet receptacle has exposed conductors.

So using a cord to connect to this disabling the interlock you would be violating multiple layers of code.

If at some point there was an injury you would be personally liable and believe me doing something like this will probably void any homeowner insurance policy in the event of someone getting injured or killed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the one fact that is being missed in this question is that what plugs into this inlet is not going to be a suicide plug. It would be an adapter with two female plugs. The adapter would be plugged in to the inlet Box and another female would be available to plug into. And yes, to convert this plug, the interlock would need to be removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/148105)